# Anonymous method in project leaks memory

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-2009

For a web framework I tried anonymous methods for the first time and ran into a problem with the memory management.

How can this memory leak (Delphi 2009) get fixed?

The leak message is:

> 13 - 20 bytes: Project27$ActRec x 1

```
program Project27;

type
  TTestProc = reference to procedure;

  procedure CallMe(Proc: TTestProc);
  begin
  end;

begin
  CallMe(procedure begin end);

  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
end.
```

---

The same leak message "Project27$ActRec x 1" appears no matter how many anonymous methods are between begin and end, I guess that the leak is for the TTestProc type, not the individual anonymous procedures

```
program Project27;

type
  TTestProc = reference to procedure;

  procedure CallMe(Proc: TTestProc);
  begin
  end;

begin

  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

  CallMe(procedure begin end);

  CallMe(procedure var A: Integer; begin A := 42 ; end);

end.
```

Comment: This was reported in 2009 as [`"QC78066 Memory leaks when using anonymous methods in the begin ... end block of program unit"`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78066). Still not fixed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you declare an anonymous method inside a procedure or function, it gets cleaned up when that routine goes out of scope.  (This is an oversimplification, but it's good enough for the current discussion.)  The problem is that the DPR's main routine does not "go out of scope."  Instead, the Delphi compiler inserts a hidden call to `System.Halt` at the end of it, which never returns.

So if you write it this way, you're going to get the memory leak notification.  You can fix it by putting the anonymous method creation inside a routine that exits normally, like so:

```
program Project27;

type
  TTestProc = reference to procedure;

  procedure CallMe(Proc: TTestProc);
  begin
  end;

  procedure Test;
  begin
    CallMe(procedure begin end);
  end;

begin
  Test;
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
end.
```

Comment: There's more to it than this in fact. If you declare an interface variable with global scope in the .dpr file, and assign to it, then that does get tidied up before the leak checking runs. Anon methods are clearly special.

Comment: @David: That's odd.  Sounds like a bug, then. Someone ought to submit a QC report for it.

Comment: Nobody should ever do anything between begin and end in the .dpr other than invoke a function written in another unit.  Even declaring the procedure directly in the .dpr is a terrible practice, and is bad style.

Comment: @Warren P Any particular reason besides "bad style"? Are there practical issues with doing this?

Comment: Update: the same leak message "Project27$ActRec x 1" appears no matter how many anonymous methods are between begin and end, I guess that the leak is for the TTestProc type, not the individual anonymous procedures

Comment: @mjn: It's because there's only one functor object created per procedure, no matter how many methods you put on it. It has to be that way to make the closure work.  See http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/13/whats-in-a-name-less-method for details.

Answer (score 11):

I guess this is because your are using the main `begin..end.` block inside the .dpr file. The hidden memory structures created within the `begin..end.` scope is not released when *FastMM4* inspects the memory, because it is not yet out of scope.

There is no memory leak if you put your anonymous method outside this main `begin..end.` block.

*My advice is to avoid putting some code inside the .dpr file - it is most of the time buggy. And the IDE does not like that. Use a separated unit for your own code, and leave the .dpr content alone.* :)

Comment: While I agree that that is the best choice for non-trivial code, I often put everything in the dpr when testing some algorithms in a console program. But even then, my anonmethos and interfaces, etc. are all local to functions (in the dpr), never in the main block.